# error in getting the response, if nodejs server send response after some delay

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, express

I am trying to upload the image, and then nodeJS server send the path of that image folder back as a response.

But When I sending the response after performing some task, nothing happening on angular-side.

this is my `component.ts` file.

```
uploadImage() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', this.image);
    const obj$ = this.userService.uploadData(formData); 
    obj$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);   //// nothing happening.
      if (data.success) {
        this.uploadForm.patchValue({
          document: data.url
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

and my `service.ts`

```
uploadData (uploadImage) {
   return this.http.post<UploadPhoto>('/user/upload', uploadImage);
  }
```

and my app.js

```
router.post('/upload' ,upload.single('photo'), (req,res) => {

  console.log(req.file);
  const body = req.file;

  cloudinary.uploader.upload(body.path, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(result);
    res.status(200).json({
      url: result.url,
      success: true
    });
  });
});
```

But when I am sending response without performing any task, it works fine like

```
router.post('/upload' ,upload.single('photo'), (req,res) => {

  console.log(req.file);
  const body = req.file;

  res.status(200).json({
       url: 'hello',
       success: true
  })

});
```

I don't know why is this happening.

Please someone help me.

Comment: Very likely a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Try to pu a breakpoint inside the callback of `cloudinary.uploader.upload()`, and see if you get there, if there are errors.

Comment: Thanx for you help. it produces an error that's why it is not sending the response properly. Now I have corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

When an error occurs in your uploader you're returning the error to the console and then ending execution.  If there is an error in the asynchronous method you must pass it to the `next()` function so that express can handle it.

```
router.post('/upload' ,upload.single('photo'), (req,res, next) => {

  console.log(req.file);
  const body = req.file;

  cloudinary.uploader.upload(body.path, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(200).json({ url: result.url, success: true });
    }
  });
});
```